# Is there a better way to find the percent of one column that meets a criteria for each value in another column for a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns `grade.equivalent` and `scaled.score`, both numeric. I'd like to find the percent of students at or above a given `scaled.score` for all students at or above each `grade.equivalent`.

For example, given the following data frame:

```
df.ex <- data.frame(grade.equivalent=c(2.4,2.7,3.1,2.5,1.4,2.2,2.3,1.7,1.3,2.2),
scaled.score=c(187,277,308,268,236,305,298,246,241,138)
)
```

I'd like to know for each `grade.equivalent`, what percent of students scored above 301 out of all students scoring at or above that `grade.equivalent`.

To do this I did the following:

```
find.percent.basic <- function(cut.ge, data, cut.scaled.score){
df.sub <- subset(data, grade.equivalent >= cut.ge & !is.na(scaled.score))
denom <- nrow(df.sub)
df.sub <- subset(df.sub, scaled.score >= cut.scaled.score)
numer <- nrow(df.sub)
return(numer/denom)
}

grade.equivs <- unique(df.ex$grade.equivalent)
grade.equivs <- grade.equivs[order(grade.equivs)]

just.percs <- sapply(grade.equivs, find.percent.basic, data=df.ex, cut.scaled.score=301)

new.df <- data.frame(grade.equivalent=grade.equivs, perc=just.percs)
```

I plan to wrap this in a function and use it with plyr.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? It seems like this might be a base function of r or a common package that I just don't know about.

Thanks for any thoughts.

EDIT for clarification
The code above produces the following result, which is what I'm looking for:

```
grade.equivalent      perc
1              1.3 0.2000000
2              1.4 0.2222222
3              1.7 0.2500000
4              2.2 0.2857143
5              2.3 0.2000000
6              2.4 0.2500000
7              2.5 0.3333333
8              2.7 0.5000000
9              3.1 1.0000000
```

Edited for clarification a second time, per observations from @DWin

Comment: If you sort by grade.equivalent you see that the first value with a scaled.score above  301 is grade 2.2. Why should we be calculating non-zero values for grades below that level? (I guess this means you trust your code more than you trust your command of the English language?)

Comment: Sort by `grade.equivalent`. The first row has a `grade.equivalent` of 1.3. I'm looking for how to find what percent of all rows that have a `grade.equivalent` of greater than or equal to that 1.3 have a `scaled.score` greater than or equal to 301. Since this is the first row, that means all of the rows in the data frame have have a `grade.equivalent` greater than or equal to 1.3. There are 10 rows, two of which have a `scaled.score` greater or equal to 301. This means the percent is correctly .2.

Comment: I see the lines in the original question that are incorrect, thanks for pointing those out. They are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean of a boolean is the percentage that are true, so something like this should do it:

```
mean(data$scaled.score >= cut.ss, na.rm=TRUE)
```

As in your comment, yes, that's exactly what you need to do.  I'd choose to access `scaled.score` slightly differently, but no real difference.

```
gs <- sort(unique(df.ex$grade.equivalent))
ps <- sapply(gs, function(cut.ge) {
  mean(df.ex$scaled.score[df.ex$grade.equivalent>=cut.ge] >= 301, na.rm=TRUE)
})
data.frame(gs, ps)

#  gs        ps
# 1.3 0.2000000
# 1.4 0.2222222
# 1.7 0.2500000
# 2.2 0.2857143
# 2.3 0.2000000
# 2.4 0.2500000
# 2.5 0.3333333
# 2.7 0.5000000
# 3.1 1.0000000
```

I don't think this is the kind of thing that will work well with `plyr`'s split-apply-combine methodology, because you can't split the data into discrete subsets for each grade-equivalent, instead, some rows will appear in multiple subsets.

Another option would be to split the scores (or the entire data frame, if needed) yourself into the desired sections, and then to apply whatever functions you wanted; this would be the same methodology as `plyr`, though more by hand.

```
scores <- lapply(gs, function(x) df.ex$scaled.score[df.ex$grade.equivalent>=x])
sapply(scores, function(x) mean(x>301, na.rm=TRUE))
```

And a final option would be to put them in order to start with and then compute a cumulative mean, and remove the duplicated `grade.equivalent` values, like this.

```
df2 <- df.ex[rev(order(df.ex$grade.equivalent)),]
df2$perc <- cumsum(df2$scaled.score>301)/1:nrow(df2)
df2 <- df2[nrow(df2):1,c("grade.equivalent", "perc")]
df2[!duplicated(df2$grade.equivalent),]
```

Comment: Sorry, grade.level should have been grade.equivalent. Changed above.

Comment: So that reduces the find.percent.basic function to: mean(data[data$grade.equivalent>=cut.ge,]$scaled.score >= cut.ss, na.rm=TRUE). That's definitely an improvement, but still requires pulling out the grade.equivalents and then applying over them. If nothing comes along better I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with(df.ex, tapply(scaled.score, INDEX=grade.equivalent, 
                   FUN=function(s) 100*sum(s>301)/length(s) ) )
#1.3 1.4 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.7 3.1 
#  0   0   0  50   0   0   0   0 100
```

Comment: I think this is just giving the percent above the cut.scaled.score of any rows at the given grade.equivalent, not at or above the grade.equivalent.

Comment: Right. You asked for those "above 301", not those "at or above". The fix is trivial if you do change your specification and want "at or above".

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear, I mean at or above that grade.equivalent, not scaled.score. See above for the output I'm looking for.

Comment: This solved the question as I wrote it, but not as I intended it. The question is edited above. Thank you for pointing that out.